# how to check if a combobox is empty without setfocus?

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

i need to know if any text has been entered into a combobox

if i do:

```
If comboReason1.Value <> "" Then
```

it gives me an error, and if i do:

```
If comboReason1.Value <> Null then
```

this doesn't work.

how do i check whether text has been entered into the combobox?

Comment: Yet another READ-THE-HELP-FILE question. What is your point in doing this? I'm going to downvote you on every one of these crappy questions and I hope others do likewise.

Comment: @David-W-Fenton To be fair "One of the goals of SO is to become the canonical place to find good answers to any programming question" --http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4448/does-so-encourage-developer-laziness

Comment: Most of these questions this yahoo is posting are not programming questions. Even when they are, they are so poorly formulated as to not be all that helpful. These posts serve neither the interests of SO nor of Access users.

Comment: I agree with Dave, people need to fire a search engine before asking here. what is the point of answering same questions again and again if people are not reading existing stuff before they ask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
If IsNull(comboReason1.Value) then
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not in a position test this quickly, but try

```
if comboReason1.Text<>"" then
```